# How to get the width/height while customizing Entry control in .NET MAUI?

Tags: controls, maui, handler

I'm trying to get the width and height of an Entry field while modifying its mapper. I read the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize) on customizing controls with handlers.

I tried using the PlatformView property to access properties of the native view, and I also tried using VirtualView to get the properties of the cross-platform control. The PlatformView width/height returned 0, and the VirtualView width/height returned NaN.

```
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyEntry", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if __ANDROID__
            // These values get set to 0
            var pv_width = handler.PlatformView.Width;
            var pv_height = handler.PlatformView.Height;

            // These values get set to NaN
            var vv_width = handler.VirtualView.Width;
            var vv_height = handler.VirtualView.Height;
#elif __IOS__
            // These values get set to 0
            var pv_width = handler.PlatformView.Bounds.Width;
            var pv_height = handler.PlatformView.Bounds.Height;

            // These values get set to NaN
            var vv_width = handler.VirtualView.Width;
            var vv_height = handler.VirtualView.Height;
#endif
        }
```

Is there a way that I can get the width and the height of the Entry while customizing its mapper?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a borderless Entry with the line underneath in iOS?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT That is correct. I'm leaning towards doing the BoxView approach mentioned by krapso's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to get the values before the view has been rendered.
I'm not sure about the intention here, but (I think) you have to postpone it or change the approach.
What do you exactly what to achieve with that?

**[Updated]**

If you would like to add an underline below an Entry you can add it like a BoxView, or if it's not an exact match for your needs then perhaps create a new handler.

Solution with the `BoxView`:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
  <Entry Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
  <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Or you can create a custom Entry with a handler:

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
  public static BindableProperty UnderlineProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Underline), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomEntry), false
  );
  public bool Underline
  {
    get => (bool)GetValue(UnderlineProperty);
    set => SetValue(UnderlineProperty, value);
  }

  public CustomEntry()
  {
  }
}
```

Create custom handler:

```
public partial class CustomEntryHandler {}
```

And iOS part:

```
    public partial class CustomEntryHandler : ViewHandler<CustomEntry, UITextField>
    {
      public CustomEntryHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper, CommandMapper commandMapper = null) : base(mapper, commandMapper)
      { }
        
      public static PropertyMapper<CustomEntry, CustomEntryHandler> CustomEntryMapper = new(ViewMapper)
      {
        [nameof(CustomEntry.Underline)] = Underline
      };
        
      protected override UITextField CreatePlatformView()
      {
        return new UITextField();
      }
        
      static void Underline(CustomEntryHandler handler, CustomEntry entry)
      {
        UITextField editText = handler.PlatformView;
        if (entry.Underline)
        {
          // Here past your code
        }
      }
    }
```

Don't forget to register the handler in MauiProgram.cs , let's say with an extension function

```
public static MauiAppBuilder ConfigureMauiHandlers(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
{
  mauiAppBuilder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
  {
    #if (ANDROID || IOS)
      handlers.AddHandler<CustomEntry, CustomEntryHandler>();
    #endif
  });

  return mauiAppBuilder;
}
```

I don't have any available device to test on, but I hope your solution could be fine, or if not, there is plenty of `UITextField` underline examples on the internet. Just rewrite it to this class.

Comment: My intention was to create an underline below the Entry on iOS. I was going to add a sublayer to the text field where the frame had a width that matched the width of the Entry, and the frame's y matched the height of the Entry minus one.

`var layer = new CALayer { Frame = new CGRect(0, handler.PlatformView.Bounds.Height - 1, handler.PlatformView.Bounds.Width, 1) }; handler.PlatformView.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);`

Comment: Maybe you can use ios constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. In the end, I decided to use [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/effects) to achieve an underline under the Entry.